# parallel request to same endpoint is blocked

Tags: java, vert.x

I have started learning vertx and adding endpoints using vertx-web. I have defined my verticle and starting my HttpServer from that verticle as shown below

```
public class Bootloader {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
   vertx.deployVerticle(WebVerticle.class.getName());
 }

}

public class WebVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
 private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebVerticle.class);

   @Override
   public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
     HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
     httpServer.requestHandler(getRouter(vertx)::accept).listen(8080);
     LOGGER.info("WebVerticle deployed");
   }

   private Router getRouter(Vertx vertx) {
     Router router = Router.router(vertx);
     registerHandlers(router);
     return router;
   }

   private void registerHandlers(Router router) {

     router.route("/foo").blockingHandler(routingContext -> {
     LOGGER.info("For request having path: /foo");
     LOGGER.info("routingContext = [" + routingContext + "]");
     LOGGER.info("thread = [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]");
     try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     routingContext.response().end("BAR");
     }, false);

   }

}
```

with this when I called /foo endpoint from different tabs I see request processing happening sequentially. Am I missing something from vetx concetps that I should understand for scaling my webapp. Please guide me where I am doing wrong and way to fix it.

Comment: You should add your INFO logs to the question.

Comment: `blockingHandler` is for non-async code.

Answer (score 0):

The request is executed on the event-loop thread. When you deploy your verticle without any additional parameters, *one* instance is deployed on *one* event loop thread.

When you invoke

```
 try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

on your request, you block this one event loop for 10 seconds, during which it can not handle any other requests, so don't do that :)

When you want to delay the response, use

```
vertx.setTimer(10000, l -> {
        //no finish your response
    });
```